# Incorrect output for score( ) function in blackjack python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, blackjack

I am trying to code a function that would take a list of integers (ranging from 1-13, representing the cards from 1 to king) resulting in a tuple where the 1st element is the total of our hand, and the 2nd element is the number of soft aces present.

Note that the function assumes an infinite deck, rather than a standard deck of 52

Here is the prompt,

> In blackjack.py, implement a function called “score”:
> `def score(cards):`
>
> The argument to this function is a list of integers representing the cards in a Blackjack hand.
> This function returns a tuple. The first element of the tuple is the total value of the hand
> according to the scoring rules of Blackjack (see above; this is not simply the sum of the integers
> in the cards list). The second element of the tuple is the number of “soft” aces that remain in
> the hand after doing any conversions from 11 → 1 to keep the hand from going bust.
> Some examples of card lists on the left and the corresponding tuple values on the right:
>
> `[ 3, 12 ]` → `(13, 0)`
>
> `[ 5, 5, 10 ]` → `(20, 0)`
>
> `[ 1, 5 ]` → `(16, 1)`
>
> `[ 1, 1, 5 ]` → `(17, 1)`

Here is my code, which produces a tuple of the same list of integers, rather than a tuple with (total_value, soft_ace_count)

```
import sys

import random

def get_card():
    ''' The function returns a random value between 1 and 13 (where 1 = Ace & 13 = King). Simulating
    an infinite deck of cards '''
    
    return random.randint(1, 13)


def score(cards):
    ''' This function will take a list of numbers and result in a tuple where the 1st element is the 
    total value of the blackjack hand.  The second element is the number of soft aces present (if any)
    '''
    

# First we begin with 0 as our total, since no cards have been dealt out
    
    total = 0

    # Code that accounts for the event that NO aces are drawn (i.e. non of them soft)
    ace_found = False
    soft = False

    # Code that accounts for the jacks(11), queens(12), and kings(13) having a value of 10 as per
    # blackjack rules
    for card in cards:
        if card.value >= 10:
            total += 10
        else:
            total += card.value

        # Code that accounts for the PRESENCE of aces
        if card.value == 1:
            ace_found = True

    # Code that accounts for the even that Aces are drawn and the conditions are such that the ace('s)
    # drawn can be considered "soft" (i.e. the value of the Ace can be considered 1 or 11)
    if total < 12 and ace_found:
        total += 10
        soft = True

    return total, soft
```

Here, the results of the code

```
>>>3, 12

(3, 12)
```

Comment: The instructions say that the function receives a list of integers. Integers don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Where is my code am I failing in this aspect? I am not an experienced programmer, so an educational approach would be much more appreciated.

Comment: If `cards` is a list of integers, `card.value` should be getting an error. `card.value` should just be `card`.

Comment: In your result transcript, you're not calling the function. You just typed a tuple. You should use `score([3, 12])`

Comment: I appreciate your help! the remainder of the comment is a copy of what I've typed in another comment. my code was correct, it was how I was entering it into the console. Stay tuned though cause I'm working on a "stand( )" function and will probably post a question about that too

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this solution?

```
def blackjack(hand):
    total = 0
    soft_aces = 0
    for card in hand:
        if card == 1:
            soft_aces += 1
            total += 11
        elif card > 10:
            total += 10
        else:
            total += card
    while total > 21 and soft_aces > 0:
        total -= 10
        soft_aces -= 1
    return (total, soft_aces)
```

Comment: I appreciate your well' detailed comment. However, @Barmar was relatively on point.  In addition, my code was correct, it was how I was entering it into the console. Stay tuned though cause I'm working on a "stand( )" function and will probably post a question about that too